# Change eclipse.ini when no access to install directory

Tags: windows, windows-8, java, environment-variables, eclipse

I'm trying to get lombok to work with eclipse. I know that I have to edit the eclipse.ini for that and I have done this before. However right now I'm using eclipse on my university computer pool and therefore cannot change anything that is not in my home directory (`%USERPROFILE%`). I found out that I can set custom enivonment variables and I already tried setting a `ECLIPSE_HOME` variable in my home dir *(I used `%USERPROFILE%\.eclipse` for `ECLIPSE_HOME` and have the a eclipse.ini at `%ECLIPSE_HOME%\eclipse.ini` (= `%USERPROFILE%\.eclipse\eclipse.ini`))*.  However it does not work.

I had two guesses on what could be wrong.

1. Eclipse doesn't read the custom `eclipse.ini`.
2. It doesn't find the lombok jar.

I'm really not sure on how to test either of these two hypotheses or what else I could try.

I also thought about installing a new instance of Eclipse in my home dir (using the installer). However this is not really practical since I have already used a large bit of my available memory and it is already taking forever to synchronize my user data to computer I'll be using.

System information:

- Windows 8
- Eclipse Juno EE

Comment: Change something in the `eclipse.ini` in your profile that would be pretty apparent in the UI/process and you'll see whenever that works? From what I can see [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) changing `Xms` should be a good indicator.